# Polygon y-intercept for x-min & x-max

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to find a solution to a problem, I have searched and the closest I can find is a post on interpolation from these forums which I have been able to achieve limited success.

I have multiple polygon's defined as separate scatter plots given by a number of x-y points. What I am attempting to do is draw a horizontal line on the y-axis and find x-min and x-max values at which the horizontal line intersects the polygon. I would like to do this for the full range of y-values. So in theory I could step through a loop and record the values at y=1, y=2 etc. An engineering software I am using requires input parameters in this format hence my attempt to find a solution.

Any advise or pointers on the best approach to this problem would be much appreciated and I will give it a go.

[image: Sample plot image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x =[1,2.6,2.56,2.57,10,11.66,13.07,11.78,11.27,6.49,5.98,5.76,3.02,1.87,1]
y =[15.59,15.09,15.14,15.15,16,17,25.47,26,27,27,28,28,26.67,16.37,15.59]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. How does the scatter plot define the polygon--is the polygon the convex hull of the points, are the points the vertices of the polygon in the given order, or something else? What do you mean by "record the values at y=1, y=2 etc." since there probably are no points with a y-coordinate of 1 or 2? Why can't  you just use the `min` and `max` functions to find what you want? And so on.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have added some code now. I would like to draw a horizontal line on the y-axis and find the x-min and x-max value at which the line intersects the graph. I would like to do this for the full range of y-values in increments of say 0.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can linearly interpolate between those two points, where the polygon crosses the line defined by `ys==?`. To find those points, you may substract the `ys` value from the `y` values of the polygon, find those points between which the sign changes and get the minimum and maximum of those points.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x =[1,2.6,2.56,2.57,10,11.66,13.07,11.78,11.27,6.49,5.98,5.76,3.02,1.87,1]
y =[15.59,15.09,15.14,15.15,16,17,25.47,26,27,27,28,28,26.67,16.37,15.59]

def findminmax(t, x, zero=0):
    t = np.array(t); x = np.array(x)
    ta = []
    p = (x-zero) > 0
    ti = np.where(np.bitwise_xor(p[1:], p[:-1]))[0]
    for i in ti:
        y_ = np.sort(x[i:i+2])
        z_ = t[i:i+2][np.argsort(x[i:i+2])]
        t_ = np.interp(zero, y_, z_)
        ta.append( t_ )
    if ta:
        return min(ta), max(ta)
    else:
        return None, None

plt.plot(x,y)

ys = np.arange(13, 29, 0.2)
result = []
for s in ys:
    mi, ma = findminmax(x,y,zero=s)
    if mi and ma:
        result.append([mi,ma,s])
        print("y = {}, minimum {}, maximum {}".format(s,mi,ma))
result=np.array(result)

plt.scatter(result[:,0],result[:,2], label="min", color="limegreen")
plt.scatter(result[:,1],result[:,2], label="max", color="crimson")

plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! I can't thank you enough for taking the time to do that for me, it is a huge help as I have spent a few days trying to produce a solution myself. Best wishes.